# No method found compiler warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

I create a class from a string, check it is valid and then check if it responds to a particular method.  If it does then I call the method.  It all works fine, except I get an annoying compiler warning: "warning: no '-setCurrentID:' method found".  Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there anyway to tell the compiler all is ok and stop it reporting a warning?

The here is the code:

```
// Create an instance of the class
id viewController = [[NSClassFromString(class) alloc] init];

// Check the class supports the methods to set the row and section
if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setCurrentID:)]) 
    {
        [viewController setCurrentID:itemID];
    }   

// Push the view controller onto the tab bar stack      
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either import the header which declares the method or just use an informal protocol in your implementation  to declare it. The compiler has to know the signature of the method.

```
@interface NSObject (MyInformalProtocol)

- (void)setCurrentID:(int)id;

@end
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, very helpful.  Cheers

Dave

Comment: For the differences between formal and informal protocols, this is a good reference, again thanks for the steer.  

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProtocols.html

Regards Dave

Comment: There's another way to get around the warning that I sometimes use when I'm lazy: NSObject's `performSelector:withObject:` instead of sending the message directly. But that's only good when your argument is an object.

Comment: Glad I could help an old-time-spectrum-kid like me.

Comment: I use this for testing private message in Unit Tests.